# How do I insert a hyperlink on a single word only in an Icon Box text?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have created a WP page using Astra and Elementor.

I would like to put a hyperlink on a single word in an "Icon Box".
However, I think I can only define a hyperlink for the entire icon box.

How could I make it so that the hyperlink is placed only on the word "here"?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to just code in a hyperlink where "here" is.

Just replace all that text in your Description box with this:

```
I would like to insert a hyperlink <a href="https://osb.com/de/index.htm">here</a>. But I don't see how I can put a link on a single word only.
```

Then remove the URL from the *Link* box

[image]